# Remove dependancies on wcf services so I can unit test the class

Tags: wcf, unit-testing

I want to remove dependencies from my classes for WCF Services.  I want to inject them into the constructor as an interface and then mock the interface when I am testing that class.

What is the best practice and the fastest way for doing this?

my class:

```
class Test
{
public IMyWCFInterface _wcf;
 public Test(IMyWCFInterface wcf)
{
_wcf=wcf;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you generate a WCF client proxy, an interface for the proxy should be generated for you. In addition, the generated client class that derives from `ClientBase&lt;TChannel&gt;` should implement that interface. Rather than depending on the class, depend on the interface, and inject an instance of the client class. That should resolve your problem.

Comment: jr, you seem to be echoing what the OP stated as his intentions yet provide no guidance ??

Comment: If he is already doing that, I'm not sure what more to offer. If a class depends on an interface, the interface can easily be mocked with a framework like Moq or RhinoMocks. Any IoC framework such as Castle Windsor, Ninject, etc. can inject instances of the client class.